# cleaner way to code with div tags?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to use div tags instead of tables so that my content is more mobile-friendly.  However, I'm pretty sure there's a cleaner way to code what I have (which does work).  Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-size:22px;"><strong>Lehigh Athletics Awards and Achievements</strong></span>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-size:18px;">2014 Convocation Highlights</span>
  <br /> 
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: auto; margin-right: 14px; text-align: center;">
  <img style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/5/6/ProgramIcon.png" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: auto; margin-right: 14px; text-align: center;">
  <iframe width="300" height="169" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fmyazgq2p7k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: auto; text-align: center;">
  <iframe width="300" height="169" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fmyazgq2p7k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;height:1em;"></div>
<hr />
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <font size="4">2014 Covocation Department Awards</font>
  <br /><font size="2"><i>Lehigh Athletics values achievements in the following areas:</i></font>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;height:1em;">
  <div style="">
    <img mediaid="9491" style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 50px;" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/5/8/Academics2.png" />
  </div>
  <div style="">
    <img mediaid="9491" style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 10px;" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/5/8/Academics2.png" />
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;height:1em;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 50px;">
      <img mediaid="9484" style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/4/15/Taryn_Carroll_0082.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 10px;">
      <img mediaid="9485" style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/4/15/Lynn_Babich_0069.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 10px;">
      <img mediaid="9485" style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/4/15/Lynn_Babich_0069.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 10px;">
      <img mediaid="9485" style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/4/15/Lynn_Babich_0069.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 10px;">
      <img mediaid="9485" style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/4/15/Lynn_Babich_0069.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, use stylesheets.

Comment: every single line doesn't have to be in its own DIV...

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com - cool. Didn't know about that.  Obviously, I'm a newbie!  Not much experience with CSS, clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Albert mentioned in the comments, you can use **[Cascading Style Sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)** instead of inline-styles in your HTML document. With CSS, you can add styles like:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Written in a CSS file once, this style will be applied to all div elements. You can additionally add **classes** and/or **IDs** to your div (or other) elements:

```
<div class="cool"></div>
<div class="cool"></div>
<footer class="cool"></footer>
```

And use CSS to apply a style to all elements with that class:

```
.cool {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm obviously a newbie.  I appreciate your simple, yet explicit answer!

Comment: This answer is really your next step.  Inline styling is bad for various reasons, but the most obvious bad thing about it is the readability that you are asking about already.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use `div` on every element. `div` is for a whole group of elements.

Second, you might wanna use a style sheet which is the easiest way to learn. You would add an `id` attribute to the element, and then you can edit your style such as

```
style="float: left; width: 18%; margin-right: 10px;"
```

or

```
mediaid="9485" style="" 
  src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/4/15/Lynn_Babich_0069.jpg"
```

on the style sheet (and it will cascade; hence **CSS**) instead of repeating it over and over again on the HTML code.

Best wishes.

Comment: Please format your post so that it is legible; Stack Exchange also has built-in code detection if you know how to use it; there are tips in a sidebar when you are writing a question/answer in case you don't know them off the top of your head.

Comment: CSS Style Sheets? Isn't that redundant? You are essentially saying "Cascading Style Sheet Style Sheet".